# I have a problem while running the Kivy Python application on the phone

Tags: python, kivy, apk, kivymd

After converting the main.py and main.kv files to the apk application while running the application on the phone, it exits automatically, and I do not know the reason.
Here is a picture of the problem that is occurring:

[image]

Is there a solution
Knowing that I did everything correctly and the application was tested on the computer before converting it into an application and it was working fine, but I do not know what is happening and what is the problem and all the libraries were written inside the buildozer file and the libraries were installed while converting the application but I do not know what is the problem here
Do you find a solution for this

Comment: It's difficult to determine the exact issue without more information. Check Logcat logs. Verify dependencies in the buildozer.spec file. Check for platform-specific code: If your code contains platform-specific code, you need to ensure that it only runs on the appropriate platform. You can use the platform module to detect the current platform and execute the code accordingly. Test on different devices. Rebuild the APK. Update Kivy, Buildozer, and other dependencies.